# Which array is best way to use in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexing

i'am new to coding,i'am using String array

```
String[] barcodedep= new String[100];
```

i want to use array to retrieve the specific data according to index and find its duplicate in particular array...

> i'am storing using this,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try{
    len2++;

            barcodedep[s2] = c.getString(TAG_BARCODE);
    }
      s2++;

    for(int temp=0;temp<=len2;temp++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_BARCODE, barcodedep[temp]);
    contactList.add(map);
    }catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> i'am having a problem to find the string is already present in that array and then i want send the edited string back to particular position...

Comment: "particular array" is that another array you already have?

Comment: for fixed-length the pure array is best choice

Comment: clearify  whether you want to find duplicate elements in the same array or want to compare with a second existing array

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid i want to find duplicate....

Comment: That code won't compile to start with :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is not an appropriate data structure for finding duplicates since you have to scan the entire thing for searches. Use a set (HashSet or TreeSet) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to use array to retrieve the specific data according to index

Use `myobj[3]` if you want to access the fourth element:

```
String fourth = myobj[3];
```

> find its duplicate in particular array

Just iterate over each element of the array and check for String quality using `.equals()`.

Comment: i've edited my post..in that i'cant able to find a particular sting or is already there using .equals() and .contains()..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find an object in the array, java.util.Arrays maybe help you.
java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Object[] array, Object value)

but it may not be the best way, the implements of Set ,such as HashSet, TreeSet, LinkedHashSet ,maybe help you.